Unable to Use Get-MessageTrace Command in Exchange Online
I’m having trouble with PowerShell and Microsoft Exchange. I’m trying to interact with Exchange Online via PowerShell to retrieve all emails received within a specified date range and display them on the screen. Here’s what I’m currently doing:
$startDate = "2023-07-01"
$endDate = "2024-07-31"
$mailbox = "user@example.com"
Get-MessageTrace -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -Recipients $mailbox | Format-Table Received, SenderAddress, Subject


First, I establish a connection to the Microsoft Exchange Online server using the following commands:
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $UserCredential.UserName -ShowProgress $true

However, when I run the Get-MessageTrace command, I receive the following error:
The term 'Get-MessageTrace' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 
I found that the module containing this command should be ExchangeOnlineManagement. When I check which commands are available in this module using:
Get-Command -Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
I get the following output:
Get-Command -Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
I have already tried running the following commands, but to no avail:
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Currently, I am using PowerShell version 7.4.3.
Any help or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Looks like that command is only available in the ExchangePowerShell module; not in ExchangeOnlineManagement..

I think its likely that the Connect-ExchangeOnline function is not fully connecting or you have a lack of permissions, the cmdlet Get-MessageTrace will get imported after you connect to exchange online, the list of cmdlets is correct for the modue ExchangeOnlineManagement. Please also note that you can only use message trace for upto 10 days in the past and you would need to use Start-HistoricalSearch for periods upto 90 days. Lastly the parameter -Recipients should be -RecipientAddress.

Update:
I am now able to use commands related to quarantine messages, such as Get-QuarantineMessage. These are part of a temporary set of commands. Their source is as follows: tmpEXO_mkifudhk.jvn
When I try to list the commands that belong to tmpEXO_mkifudhk.jvn, only those related to quarantine messages are displayed. There is no trace of Get-MessageTrace.

Here are the commands I executed to make them appear (Given the inability to format this message correctly, each command begins when I use the following character "@"):
@ Uninstall-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
@ Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Force
@ Get-InstalledModule ExchangeOnlineManagement | Format-List Name, Version, InstalledLocation
@ Import-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Force
@ Connect-ExchangeOnline
@ Get-Command -Name Get-QuarantineMessage
@ Get-QuarantineMessage

If you're posting code to add information your question you can use the Edit link. If the code is a solution you should be able to post it as an answer.
